# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE calling JS over HTTPS

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I have a site which is served over HTTPS. On a particular page of this site I am calling a script from another domain.

However every time I load the page the script fails to load. Instead I see this error message in my console:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

When I click on the URL the script is being called from within the console I see this message:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

The thing that confuses me is that this was all working perfectly before I enabled HTTPS on my website.

Could anyone advise on what exactly is going wrong and what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Is the script call to another domain on HTTP? I imagine this would be the problem. As you are displaying none HTTPS content to a HTTP frame.

Comment: @RichardDakin - Yes it is, that would make sense! So I'd need to ensure that the content I'm displaying is HTTPS. This would also explain why it worked originally without HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the script call to another domain on HTTP? I imagine this would be the problem. As you are displaying none HTTPS content to a HTTP frame.

Move the external call to HTTPS and this will resolve the issue.